# Can a Halal act be evil?

Tags: halal-haram, kufr

If an act is considered Islamically permissible(but not obligatory or recommended) is it blasphemous to consider that act to be evil?
is the story different if that act is considered recommended or obligatory?

Comment: By definition, if an act is evil, it will no longer be considered halal.

Comment: @murshed Can you elaborate with an example?

Comment: For example if someone considered cousin marriage or marriage to people who are islamically adults(past the age of puberty) but are not conisdered adults universally(under 18) to be evil. is that kufr?

Comment: If that is what you are talking about then, yes. It would be kufr to consider something Allah made permissible to be evil. Why would Allah make something halal that he knows to be evil?

Comment: I wonder if talaq (divorce) out of anger is an example.

Comment: We know that incest is evil. So why did Allah allow it during the time of Adam? Can this fact not be used by people to claim Allah allows evil?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible. By definition if Allah allows it and makes it halal it is not an evil act. To declare something Allah made permissible and good as evil (based on other systems of morality) would be Kufr al-Istibdal:

> "**Today the good things are made lawful for you**, and the food of the ones to whom the Book was brought is lawful to you, and your food is made lawful to them. And (so) are believing women in wedlock, and in wedlock women of (the ones) to whom the Book was brought even before you when you have brought them their rewards in wedlock, other than in fornication, neither taking them to yourselves as mates (i.e., girl-friends). And whoever disbelieves in belief, (i.e., the religion) then his deed has been frustrated and in the Hereafter he is among the losers." (5:5)

So, everything Allah has made lawful is pure, good, or at the very least not evil.